# Ways to execute this code under 4 seconds given large inputs?

Tags: python, performance

**NOTE:** I CAN NOT use any external module that is not built-in to python.

**Problem:**

A new and upcoming artist has a unique way to create checkered patterns. The idea is to
use an M-by-N canvas which is initially entirely black. Then the artist repeatedly chooses
a row or column and runs their magic brush along the row or column. The brush changes
the colour of each cell in the row or column from black to gold or gold to black.
Given the artist’s choices, your job is to determine how much gold appears in the pattern
determined by these choices.

**Input Specification**

The first line of input will be a positive integer M. The second line of input will be a positive
integer N. The third line of input will be a positive integer K. The remaining input will be
K lines giving the choices made by the artist. Each of these lines will either be R followed
by a single space and then an integer which is a row number, or C followed by a single space
and then an integer which is a column number. Rows are numbered top down from 1 to M.
Columns are numbered left to right from 1 to N.

**Output Specification**

Output one non-negative integer which is equal to the number of cells that are gold in the
pattern determined by the artist’s choices.

**Limitations**

M and N can be up to 5 000 000

K can be up to 1 000 000

**My Solution**

```py
    import sys
    raw_input = sys.stdin.readline
    m = int(raw_input())
    n = int(raw_input())
    brushes = raw_input()
    stroke = []
    
    colors = [['B' for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
    for i in range(int(brushes)):
        g = raw_input().split(' ')
        if stroke.count(g) == 1:
            stroke.remove(g)
        else:
            stroke.append(g)
    def changeColumn(num,colors,index):
        if num == 0:
            return colors
        colors[num-1][index] = 'G' if colors[num-1][index] == 'B' else 'B'
        num -= 1
        changeColumn(num,colors,index)
                
    def countGold(c,options,i):
        if options == []:
            s = 0
            for l in c:
                s += l.count("G")
            print(s)
            return
        area = options[i][0]
        times = int(options[i][1]) - 1
        if area == "R":
            c[times] = list(''.join(c[times]).replace("G","A").replace("B","G").replace("A","B"))
        elif area == "C":
            changeColumn(m,c,times)
            
    
        
        options.remove(options[i])
        countGold(c,options,i)
        
    countGold(colors,stroke,0)
```

Got everything right except for some problems. I exceeded the Time Limit of 4 seconds. I know that making `colors` takes up a lot of time. Is there any way to do this without generating the 2d array?

**UPDATED CODE (doesn't work)**

```py
import sys
M = int(input())
N = int(input())
K = int(input())
dup = []
numR = 0
numC = 0

for i in range(K):
    choice = input().split()
    if choice not in dup:
        if choice[0] == "R":
            numR += 1
        elif choice[0] == "C":
            numC += 1
        dup.append(choice)


print((M * numR) + (N * numC) - (2*numR*numC))
```

Comment: Please make this a [mre]. You haven’t defined stroke in your code.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy apologies, fixed it now

Comment: This is an algorithmic issue. Here are some observations: all of those operations are commutative, i.e. we can rearrange them however we want. Secondly: we can first look at rows (or columns). This will give us the total number of marked rows X. Which gives us XM gold cells. Then we look at columns, this gives us total number of marked columns Y. And this gives us the total number of marked cells as YN. Then we need to remove intersections which is YX. Total formula is XM+YN-XY. Remember to deal with duplicate rows and columns. You don't need to construct and fill matrix at all.

Comment: @freakish so let's say there are 4 columns and 5 rows. The pattern is R 2, R 1, R 3, C 1, and C 4. We have row 1,2,3 and column 1 and 4 marked. Would the formula be: 3(4) + 2(5) - 3(2)?

Comment: @AK-10CA-GlenforestSS2172 Yes, I think so (please double check it though). The final result is 16. Note that you may have duplicates in the input, i.e. R2, R2, R1, R3, C1, C4. Which gives you 2(4)+2(5)-2(2)=14. Duplicates cancel each other out.

Comment: @freakish weird because when i tested it with the program above, I got 10, not 14

Comment: @AK-10CA-GlenforestSS2172 ah, sorry, we need to remove the intersection twice (one time for rows and one time for columns). It should be XM+YN-2XY. This should give the correct result. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @freakish this is still not fast enough. idk how. I'm exceeding the time limit of 4 seconds when N or M <= 1 000 000 or K <= 5 000 000

Comment: @freakish also now im getting some answer rights and some answers wrong.  Updated code is above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229031/discussion-between-ak-10ca-glenforest-ss-2172-and-freakish).

Comment: @AK-10CA-GlenforestSS2172 what you are doing is not an efficient way to find duplicates. Use a set `dup = set()` instead of list (scanning list is expensive). Also the reason you get incorrect results sometimes is because you scan for duplicates but don't actually use `dup` anywhere. One loop to build `dup` set. Then second loop over `dup` with `r += 1` and `c += 1` inside (you can optimize this with a single loop and `r -= 1` on duplicate if you want).

Comment: @freakish updated the code again and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Let me put all that discussion in comments into the code:

```py
import sys
M = int(input())
N = int(input())
K = int(input())
dup = set()
result = {'numR': 0, 'numC': 0}

def update(char, num):
    if char == 'R':
        result['numR'] += num
    elif char == 'C':
        result['numC'] += num

for i in range(K):
    choice = input().split()
    if choice in dup:
        dup.remove(choice)
        update(choice[0], -1)
    else:
        dup.add(choice)
        update(choice[0], 1)

numR = result['numR']
numC = result['numC']

print((M * numR) + (N * numC) - (2*numR*numC))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code sent by Freakish still doesn't work for some reason. Here is an updated code that works:

```py
import sys
rw = sys.stdin.readline
M = int(rw())
N = int(rw())
choices = set()
K = int(rw())
for i in range(K):
    g = input()
    if g in choices:
        choices.remove(g)
    else:
        choices.add(g)


numR = 0
numC = 0
s = 0
for choice in choices:
    if choice[0] == "R":
        numR += 1
    elif choice[0] == "C":
        numC += 1


for choice in choices:
    if choice[0] == "R":
        # numR += 1
        s += N - numC
    elif choice[0] == "C":
        # numC += 1
        s += M - numR


print(s)
```